# How to get result only for spesified ID's in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i am working on college ERP software where i couldn't be able to find solution on following problem. here i am shortly explain the problem

Table Student.

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | enroll | sub_id |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 |      1 |      2 |
|  3 |      2 |      1 |
|  4 |      2 |      2 |
|  5 |      2 |      3 |
|  6 |      3 |      1 |
|  7 |      3 |      2 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Requirement - In student table, fetch only those enroll no.  which have sub_id 1 & 2 if any enroll no. have assign 1,2 & 3 then it should not be come into the result.

I try to us **IN** function but i won't give right results.
Please suggest me solution for this problem.
Thanx...

Comment: Show... 1. how you tried to use IN function... 2. what the correct output would look like

Comment: select * from trial where sub_id in (1,2); By using this query i got result enroll 1,2 and 3.  But i am expecting result 1 and 3 only because enroll 2 have additional sub_id 3.

Comment: @Barmar That's not a duplicate question - no need for Group By or Having - sets within sets. This is a basic Select In question

Comment: @dbmitch No it isn't, because he wants to exclude students who have other  `sub_id`s. The duplicate question shows how to match exactly a specific set of IDs.

Comment: @Barmar - so my basic select does not answer his question? I must really misunderstand what he's asking for. I thought the Select from (select IN) is exactly what he needed. He doesn't mention student ids at all - just enroll nums

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.enroll, t1.sub_id
FROM Student t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT enroll,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sub_id IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS subCount
    FROM Student
    GROUP BY enroll
    HAVING subCount = 2 AND COUNT(*) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.enroll = t2.enroll
```

The trick in this query is the `HAVING` clause, which restricts to enrollments which have `(1, 2)` sub enrolled, and *only* `(1, 2)` sub enrolled.

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: it's working perfectly.....!!!! Thank you sir......

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time figuring out exactly what you want from your description but this returns 1, 3 for your example

```
SELECT DISTINCT enroll FROM Student
WHERE enroll NOT IN 
(SELECT enroll FROM Student WHERE sub_id NOT IN (1,2))
```

Comment: In my example all enroll have sub_id 1 and 2, but enroll 2 also have sub_id 3, so i need to exclude enroll 2 from result. I required those enroll which only have sub_id 1 and 2.

Comment: So this works for you? It only returns 1 and 3 as you suggested

Comment: This doesn't work in this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdecd8/1 I added enroll 4 that only has `sub_id = 1` but not `sub_id = 2`. It's included in the result but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Gotcha - makes sense to me now!